# Discrete, dense, and continuous trees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, order-theory, trees

Assuming we use the set-theoretic definition of a tree:
A set $T$ with a partial order $<$ is a tree if for any $t \in T$
the set $\{ s \in T : s < t \}$ is well-ordered by $<$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(set_theory)

We know how to define discrete, dense, and continuous linear orders using cuts:

- A linear order is discrete if every cut of it is a jump;
- A linear order is dense if it contains no jumps;
- A dense linear order is continuous if it contains no gaps.

Is there a reason to not use the types of orders in trees?
Can we define discrete, dense, and continuous trees the same way?

My attempt:

A set $T$ with a partial order $\le$ is a discrete (resp. dense, continuous) tree if for any $t \in T$:

1. the set $S = \{ s \in T : s \le t \}$ is totally ordered by $\le$, and
2. the total order of $S$ is discrete (resp. dense, continuous).

If we add the connectivity property:

3. for any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $T$ there is an element $z$ such that $z \le x$ and $z \le y$,

it looks like the new definition includes the sets of real trees:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_tree

Does it make sense?

Now, assuming we separated discrete and continuous trees using the order type.

Let's take a set $T = \{0\} \cup \mathbb T$ with the partial order $x < y \iff |x| < |y|$,
where $\mathbb T = \{ z \in \mathbb C : |z| = 1 \}$ is the unit circle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group),
and $0 = (0,0)$ is the center of the circle.

According to my definition, $T$ is a discrete tree.
But $T$ contains an uncountable (not discrete) subset $\mathbb T$.
What kind of tree is it?

Answer (score 1):

In your example, $(\{0\}\cup\mathbb T,<)$ does not know about the elements of $\mathbb T$ forming a continuous circle in $\mathbb C$.

You'd get an isomorphic tree when taking a discrete set $X$ with cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ and let $T'=\{0\}\cup X$ with $0<x$ for all $x\in X$ and the elements of $X$ incomparable.

Comment: Is $T$ indeed a discrete tree in discrete mathematics (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(graph_theory))? Can I use my definitions of discrete, dense, and continuous trees? If yes, then any set can be a subset of a discrete tree, meaning the set is discrete too.