# Cycle-tree order relation

Tags: relations, order-theory, trees

I am trying to express a cycle-tree structure (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3835246/427611) as an ordered set.

I want to extend the notion of a cycle-tree structure onto continuous structures as well.

Here is what I got so far:

1. A set $T$ with a partial order $\le$ is a tree if for any element $t$ of $T$ the set $\{ s \in T : s \le t \}$ is totally ordered by $\le$;
2. A tree $T$ is connected if for any two elements $x$ and $y$ of $T$ there is an element $z$ such that $z \le x$ and $z \le y$;
3. A branch of a tree is a *maximal* totally ordered subset of the tree.

([Discrete, dense, and continuous trees](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3838239/427611))

4. A partial order $\le$ is *compatible* with a cyclic order $(x, y, z)$ on a set $C$ if $\le$ is a subset of a *cut* of $(x, y, z)$.
5. A cycle-tree is a tree $T(\le)$ with a cyclic order $(x, y, z)$ on a subset $C$ of $T$ such that:

   - $\le$ is *compatible* with $(x, y, z)$ on $C$;
   - if $t \le c$ for some elements $t$ of $T$ and $c$ of $C$, then $t \in C$;
6. A cycle-tree is connected if every branch of $T$ has an element from $C$.
7. A cycle-tree is discrete if both $T$ and $C$ are discrete.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_order)

Is this definition equivalent to the existing one (via directed graphs) in case of discrete structures?
Would it be a correct generalization onto non-discrete structures?

Are there other definitions of a cycle-tree structure via binary and/or ternary relations?
Since any total order induces a cyclic order and vice versa, is there an elegant way to express a cycle-tree as a pure binary or ternary relation on a set?

**Update**

A branch of a cycle-tree can be viewed as a cut of a *round* of a partial cyclic order.
Together with the cycle itself the rounds of all the branches form a *ROCO*:

https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01360144/document

Obviously, not every *ROCO* can be "cut" into a cycle-tree.
What are the conditions for a *ROCO* to represent a cycle-tree structure?

Comment: I've seen your comment, and see that I have misunderstood. I'll take a look again later today and try see if I can find a nice formalisation.

Comment: The relation you want is exactly the graph $\{ (x, f(x)) \in X^2 \}$ of the original function $f$. This is a directed graph in which the outdegree of every vertex is exactly $1$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How do we find the $f(x)$ for continuous trees, e.g for the tree on $\mathbb R$: $x \le_{\small T} y \iff 0 \le xy \land |x| \le |y|$ ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to do. If you're trying to generalize the cycle-tree decomposition I described to functions on infinite sets then you're starting with a function $f$ and analyzing its graph. If you're trying to do something else then I don't know.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am trying to define a continuous cycle-tree as a "composition" of "pure" order relations, with no graphs. I am not sure if it is possible or convenient, but I want to know advantages and disadvantages of the approach. Your input is valuable to me. Thank you.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez I started thinking that you were correct that a cycle-tree is a partial cyclic order. Just not any partial cyclic order: it is not necessarily *globally oriented* and not an arbitrary *ROCO*: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01360144/document